# Windows 11 Setup stuck at the "Making sure you're ready to install" stage

Tags: windows-11-upgrade

I'm trying to use the "Windows 11 Installation Assistant" approach to upgrade from Windows 10 from https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11. However, after seemingly progressing fine, it gets stuck at this stage (for several hours instead of "a few minutes", and it's the second time). [image: Stuck install]

Can I somehow remove its previous attempts completely in case the download is corrupted and retry it? Or should I try "Create Windows 11 Installation Media" instead?

Comment: I have seen this step stall for 15 - 20 minutes - not hours.  Make sure your computer is Windows 11 compliant. (Microsoft PC 11 check), and then use the Windows 11 media instead to see.

Comment: Health check passes, and Windows Update shows "Great news—your PC meets the minimum system requirements for Windows 11. Specific timing for when it will be offered can vary as we get it ready for you.".

Comment: Yes, I'd use the Windows Media Creation Tool to put it on USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with the USB install as well. What finally fixed it is clicking the little "Change how Setup downloads updates" link at the first screen here [image: Windows 11 Setup screenshot] and then selecting "Not right now". [image: Second Windows 11 Setup screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After aborting the first attempt which had been stuck at the 'Making sure you're ready to install' stage for several hours, I had a major DUH! moment. I realised I had not elected to run the set-up file as an Administrator.

On the next attempt I right-clicked on Set-up, opted to 'Run as Adminstrator' and installation started and completed with no issues.